Plotting subplots in Matplotlib: second plot not showing data
I am trying to create subplots in Matplotlib where the first plot is a stacked bar plot and the second plot is a line plot. Both plots should share the same datetime index for the x-axis. However, I am facing an issue where the second plot does not show any data.
             Economizer  Economizer_plus_Mech  ...  Not_Mechanical     OaTemp
2023-10-01    1.680672              1.680672  ...        1.680672  84.317815
2023-10-02   17.127072              5.524862  ...        1.657459  76.263536
2023-10-03   31.481481              5.092593  ...        0.000000  73.407407

Here is my plot function:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import pandas as pd

PLOTS_DIR = 'path/to/plots'

def save_mode_plot_with_oat(combined_data, title, ylabel, filename):
    # Ensure the index is datetime
    combined_data.index = pd.to_datetime(combined_data.index)

    # Create a 2-row subplot layout, sharing the x-axis
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12, 12), sharex=True)

    # Bar plot for mode percentages on the first subplot
    combined_data.iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax1, colormap='viridis')
    ax1.set_title(title)
    ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    # Hide x-label on the first plot
    ax1.set_xlabel('')
    ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelbottom=False)  # Hide x-tick labels on the first plot

    # Line plot for outside air temperature on the second subplot
    ax2.plot(combined_data.index, combined_data['OaTemp'], color='red', linestyle='-', marker='o')
    ax2.set_title('Average Outside Air Temperature Over Time')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Average Outside Air Temperature (°F)')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax2.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)  # Rotate x-tick labels on the second plot
    ax2.grid(True)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(PLOTS_DIR, filename))
    plt.close()

# Example call
save_mode_plot_with_oat(month_df, 'Mode Percentages and OAT', 'Percentage (%)', 'mode_oat_plot.png')

My plots come through like this where the second plot is always blank. What can I try next?


Bar plots in matplotlib have a categorical x-axis, and the ticks are at integer values 0, 1, 2, .... This does not align with your line plot.

The pandas DataFrame.plot.bar API uses the index as a categorical variable to group the data, but the x-values of the plot are just 0 to the number of categories (minus 1).  I.e. the actual VALUES of the x-ticks of ax1 are going to to be 0 to 31, while the labels are the string representations of the index.
Contrary to this, the DataFrame.plot.line API and the matplotlib.pyplot.plot API convert the dates to the number of days since the epoch start (Jan 1, 1970) for the values of the x-ticks.
The values of the x-ticks for the two axes are fundamentally different.  So what can we do?  Manually construct one of the graphs instead of using the high-level API.  In this case, we can build the bar chart by stacking up each column in the data frame and aligning them on the x-axis to the days since the epoch start.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colormaps


def save_mode_plot_with_oat(combined_data, title, ylabel, filename):
    # Ensure the index is datetime, get days since epoch
    combined_data.index = pd.to_datetime(combined_data.index)
    epoch_days = (combined_data.index.to_series() - pd.to_datetime('1970-1-1')).dt.days

    # Create a 2-row subplot layout, sharing the x-axis
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12, 12), sharex=True)

    # Bar plot for mode percentages on the first subplot
    cols = combined_data.columns[:-1]
    cmap = colormaps.get('viridis')
    prev_y_vals = 0

    # plot each column values as a bar on top of the previous bar values
    for i, col in enumerate(cols):
        y_vals = combined_data.loc[:, col] + prev_y_vals
        ax1.bar(epoch_days, height=y_vals, bottom=prev_y_vals, c=cmap(i))
        prev_y_vals = y_vals

    ax1.set_title(title)
    ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    ax1.set_xlabel('')
    ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelbottom=False)  

    # Line plot for outside air temperature on the second subplot
    ax2.plot(combined_data.index, combined_data['OaTemp'], color='red', linestyle='-', marker='o')
    ax2.set_title('Average Outside Air Temperature Over Time')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Average Outside Air Temperature (°F)')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax2.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)  # Rotate x-tick labels on the second plot
    ax2.grid(True)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(PLOTS_DIR, filename))
    plt.close()

